# SQL Server backup&restore

Tags: c#, sql-server, backup, restore

**backup**

```
string connectionString1 = (@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database1.mdf;Database=Database1;Integrated Security=True; User Instance=True");
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString1);
            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataReader reader;
            cmd.CommandText = @"BACKUP DATABASE Database1 TO DISK = 'C:\SRI2Works.bak'";

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            cn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Database Backup Successfull.");
```

**restore**

```
string connectionString1 = (@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database1.mdf;Database=Database1;Integrated Security=True; User Instance=True");
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString1);
            cn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataReader reader;
            cmd.CommandText = @"use master; RESTORE DATABASE Database1 FROM DISK = 'C:\SRI2Works.bak'";
            cmd.CommandText = "DBCC CHECKDB ('Database1')";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            cn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Database Restored Successfull.");
```

This code runs successfully but doesn't make any changes.

Comment: How did you verify that the code was indeed executed? Did the message box fire?

Comment: Is the file `C:\SRI2Works.bak` actually written? And, as it is, your restore command only executes `DBCC CHECKDB ('Database1')` which replaces the `CommandText` set in the line above.

Comment: @ThomasGerstendörfer good catch! The OP should use SQL Profiler to verify that the expected commands are actually sent.

Comment: I don't think you can use the usual `BACKUP` and `RESTORE` commands against `.mdf` files that are being attached using `AttachDbFileName=` in SQL Server Express. As far as I know, your database has to be **attached to the SQL Server instance** in order for it to be able to backed up with `BACKUP DATABASE`...

Comment: Check out [How to Backup and Restore SQL Server Express databases](http://weblogs.asp.net/morteza/archive/2009/10/08/how-to-backup-and-restore-sql-express-2005-attachdbfilename-mode.aspx) - the "auto-attached" database is attached with a name that matches the **full path** of the `.mdf` file (including drive and directories) and you need to use that full path as your database name when doing `BACKUP` and `RESTORE`

Answer (score 7):

Try this code in Restore database:

```
    private void restoreButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string database = con.Database.ToString();
    if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    try
    {
        string sqlStmt2 = string.Format("ALTER DATABASE [" + database + "] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE");
        SqlCommand bu2 = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt2, con);
        bu2.ExecuteNonQuery();

        string sqlStmt3 = "USE MASTER RESTORE DATABASE [" + database + "] FROM DISK='" + textBox2.Text + "'WITH REPLACE;";
        SqlCommand bu3 = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt3, con);
        bu3.ExecuteNonQuery();

        string sqlStmt4 = string.Format("ALTER DATABASE [" + database + "] SET MULTI_USER");
        SqlCommand bu4 = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt4, con);
        bu4.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("database restoration done successefully");
        con.Close();

   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
   }
}
```

For more explanation check out this tutorial: [Backup & Restore Sql Server database using C#](http://www.csharp-tutorials1.blogspot.com/2016/03/backup-and-restore-sql-server-database.html)

Comment: It was awesome. Saved my time. and +1 for reference link also :)

Answer (score 0):

for example we have 2 Menu Strip; one for back up and the other for the restore so they execute their methods! Try this :

```
    private void saveDatabaseToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            BackupDatabase();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + " \nPlease choose the folder Sauvegardes to backup !");
        }

    }
    private void restoreDatabaseToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            RestoreDatabase();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    private void BackupDatabase()
    {
        saveFileDialogBackUp.InitialDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Sauvegardes";
        if (saveFileDialogBackUp.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Con.ExecuteCmd("BACKUP DATABASE MyFooDatabase TO DISK = '" + saveFileDialogBackUp.FileName + "'");
            MessageBox.Show("Success , done!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
    private void RestoreDatabase()
    {
        openFileDialogBackUp.InitialDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Sauvegardes";
        if (openFileDialogBackUp.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Con.ExecuteCmd(" USE MASTER RESTORE DATABASE MyFooDatabase FROM DISK = '"+openFileDialogBackUp.FileName+"' WITH REPLACE");
            MessageBox.Show("Database Restored", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following statement from your code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "DBCC CHECKDB ('Database1')";
```

And If you want to overwrite the existing database use the following command for commandtext:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"use master; RESTORE DATABASE Database1 FROM DISK = 'C:\SRI2Works.bak' WITH REPLACE";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RESTORE DATABASE [C] FROM DISK = 'D:\\Inventory.bak' WITH RECOVERY, 
MOVE 'Inventory_Data'
 TO 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL\\Data\\c_Data.MDF', 
MOVE 'Inventory_Log' 
TO 
'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL\\Data\\c_Log.LDF', 
REPLACE, stats =1
```

The only thing you have to care about, restore database is not created in MS SQL SERVER. In my case after query run it should create a new database with the name `[C]` and create its file at path of `[C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL\\Data\\]`